# Applying group by and sum on array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend

I need some advice on the proper way to attain my goal of applying group by and sum on JSON data.

Some server-side code actually generates a JSON that I have to work with :

```
[
    {
        "siteDetails": {
            "printerCode": "660103684",
            "siteId": "UTT212303-STB-2040-0003"
        },
        "printingMaterialCode": "400000033",
        "printingQuantity": 400,
        "approved": true
    },
    {
        "siteDetails": {
            "printerCode": "660103684",
            "siteId": "UTT212303-STB-2040-0002"
        },
        "printingMaterialCode": "400000033",
        "printingQuantity": 600,
        "campaignId": "DATAS00002",
    },
    {
        "siteDetails": {
            "printerCode": "660103684",
            "siteId": "UTT212303-STB-2040-0001"
        },
        "printingMaterialCode": "400000034",
        "printingQuantity": 300,
        "campaignId": "DATAS00002",
    }
]
```

Now, I need to apply some operation (maybe groupby and sum) to get the below result :

```
[
    {
        "printingMaterialCode": "400000033",
        "printingQuantity": 1000
        "approvedQuantity": 400
    },
    {
        "printingMaterialCode": "400000034",
        "printingQuantity": 300,
    }
]
```

Basically, the output is printingQuantity and approvedQuantity **SUM** per printingMaterialCode.

Comment: there is no `approvedQuantity` in any provided input.

Comment: @MohitSharma I think that would be synthesized by looking for the "approved" property being `true`.

Comment: @MohitSharma , It would be calculated based on approved property

Comment: @Andreas , I have tried to use reduce function to apply group by and sum operation and successfully getting the printing quantity sum per printingMaterialCode but I am not able to figure out how to incorporate approved quantity into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const myData = [
    {
        "siteDetails": {
            "printerCode": "660103684",
            "siteId": "UTT212303-STB-2040-0003"
        },
        "printingMaterialCode": "400000033",
        "printingQuantity": 400,
        "approved": true
    },
    {
        "siteDetails": {
            "printerCode": "660103684",
            "siteId": "UTT212303-STB-2040-0002"
        },
        "printingMaterialCode": "400000033",
        "printingQuantity": 600,
        "campaignId": "DATAS00002",
    },
    {
        "siteDetails": {
            "printerCode": "660103684",
            "siteId": "UTT212303-STB-2040-0001"
        },
        "printingMaterialCode": "400000034",
        "printingQuantity": 300,
        "campaignId": "DATAS00002",
    }
]

function elaborateMyData(myData) {
  const approvedQuantity = {};
  const printingQuantity = {};
  const myOutput = [];

  myData.forEach((v) => {
    printingQuantity[v.printingMaterialCode] = printingQuantity[v.printingMaterialCode] || 0;
    approvedQuantity[v.printingMaterialCode] = approvedQuantity[v.printingMaterialCode] || 0;

    printingQuantity[v.printingMaterialCode] += v.printingQuantity;

    if (v.approved) {
      approvedQuantity[v.printingMaterialCode] += v.printingQuantity
    }

  })

  Object.keys(printingQuantity).forEach((v) => {
    myOutput.push({
      printingMaterialCode: v,
      printingQuantity: printingQuantity[v],
      approvedQuantity: approvedQuantity[v],
    })
  })

  return myOutput
}

console.log(elaborateMyData(myData))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can build this on `reduce` in a fairly straightforward manner, with something like this:

```js
const combine = (xs) => Object .entries (xs .reduce (
  (a, {printingMaterialCode, printingQuantity, approved = false}) => {
    const pmc = a [printingMaterialCode] || {printingQuantity: 0}
    pmc .printingQuantity += printingQuantity
    if (approved) pmc .approvedQuantity = (pmc .approvedQuantity || 0) + printingQuantity
    a [printingMaterialCode] = pmc
    return a
  },
  {}
)) .map (([printingMaterialCode, rest]) => ({printingMaterialCode, ...rest}))

const input = [{siteDetails: {printerCode: "660103684", siteId: "UTT212303-STB-2040-0003"}, printingMaterialCode: "400000033", printingQuantity: 400, approved: !0}, {siteDetails: {printerCode: "660103684", siteId: "UTT212303-STB-2040-0002"}, printingMaterialCode: "400000033", printingQuantity: 600, campaignId: "DATAS00002"}, {siteDetails: {printerCode: "660103684", siteId: "UTT212303-STB-2040-0001"}, printingMaterialCode: "400000034", printingQuantity: 300, campaignId: "DATAS00002"}]

console .log (combine (input))
```

But I think it's cleaner to use some generic helper functions to handle the grouping and summing, and make your code a little more specific to your requirements, with something like this:

```js
const group = (fn) => (xs) => Object .values (
  xs .reduce ((a, x, _, __, k = fn (x)) => ((a [k] = [... a [k] || [], x]), a), {})
)

const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const combine = (xs) => 
  group (x => x.printingMaterialCode) (xs)
    .map ((xs) => ({
      printingMaterialCode : xs [0] .printingMaterialCode, 
      printingQuantity: sum (xs .map (x => x .printingQuantity)),
      approvedQuantity: sum (xs .filter (x => x.approved) .map (x => x .printingQuantity))
    }))

const input = [{siteDetails: {printerCode: "660103684", siteId: "UTT212303-STB-2040-0003"}, printingMaterialCode: "400000033", printingQuantity: 400, approved: !0}, {siteDetails: {printerCode: "660103684", siteId: "UTT212303-STB-2040-0002"}, printingMaterialCode: "400000033", printingQuantity: 600, campaignId: "DATAS00002"}, {siteDetails: {printerCode: "660103684", siteId: "UTT212303-STB-2040-0001"}, printingMaterialCode: "400000034", printingQuantity: 300, campaignId: "DATAS00002"}]

console .log (combine (input))
```

Here, **`group`** takes a key-extraction function and returns a function which takes an array of values and return an array of arrays of the elements which map to the same key.  So for instance, to group an array of numbers by their last digits, we could do this:

```js
group (n => n % 10) ([1, 12, 3, 52, 11, 56, 13, 32])
  //=> [[1, 11], [12, 52, 32], [3, 13], [56]]
```

If you're using a library that has a `groupBy` function, then you could replace this with something like

```js
const group = (fn) => (xs) => Object .values (groupBy (fn, xs))
                                      // or   groupBy (xs, fn))
                                      // or   groupBy (fn) (xs))
                                      // based on `groupBy`'s sig
```

**`sum`**, of course, just totals an array of numbers.

So **`combine`** then groups the numbers into like `printingMaterialCode` values, then `map`s the result into an object with your requested properties.

This has one difference from your requested structure, and that is that the group that has no `approved` entries, still has an `approvedQuantity` field; it's just set to zero.  I personally prefer this behavior, as consistent data is always a win.  But if you wanted to change that, you could replace this line:

```js
      approvedQuantity: sum (xs .filter (x => x.approved) .map (x => x .printingQuantity))
```

with this:

```js
      ... (xs .some (x => x.approved) 
        ? {approvedQuantity: sum (xs .filter (x => x.approved) .map (x => x .printingQuantity))} 
        : {}
      )
```

However, that introduces some ugliness to our function.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Map` as:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        siteDetails: {
            printerCode: '660103684',
            siteId: 'UTT212303-STB-2040-0003',
        },
        printingMaterialCode: '400000033',
        printingQuantity: 400,
        approved: true,
    },
    {
        siteDetails: {
            printerCode: '660103684',
            siteId: 'UTT212303-STB-2040-0002',
        },
        printingMaterialCode: '400000033',
        printingQuantity: 600,
        campaignId: 'DATAS00002',
    },
    {
        siteDetails: {
            printerCode: '660103684',
            siteId: 'UTT212303-STB-2040-0001',
        },
        printingMaterialCode: '400000034',
        printingQuantity: 300,
        campaignId: 'DATAS00002',
    },
];

const map = new Map();
arr.forEach((o) => {
    const { printingMaterialCode, printingQuantity, approved } = o;
    const objInMap = map.get(printingMaterialCode);
    if (objInMap) {
        if (approved) {
            if (objInMap.approvedQuantity) objInMap.approvedQuantity = (objInMap.approvedQuantity ?? 0) + printingQuantity;
        }
        objInMap.printingQuantity += printingQuantity;
    } else {
        const newObj = { printingMaterialCode, printingQuantity };
        if (approved) newObj.approvedQuantity = printingQuantity;
        map.set(o.printingMaterialCode, newObj);
    }
});

const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result);
```